# Is there any way for me to send the longtitude and latitude to a webhook?

Tags: javascript, html, webhooks

I am trying to send the longitude and latitude of a device to a discord webhook (or any webhook in general), I can not seem to find a way to take the longitude and latitude values to successfully be sent to the webhook.

The problem here is that even after converting the latitude and longitude into variables the webhook refuses to work? I tried a lot of ways, none seemed to send the longitude or latitude or both.

Thank you in advance, please try sending the values to your own webhook, make one on discord (it is 100% free) before putting an answer.

Please note that I am fairly new to javascript, I am more confortable with python and Lua C.
Please if you have an answer try providing a example with it, saves me from a headache.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<button onclick="sendMessage()">Send your location to my webhook</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function sendMessage() {
      
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "PUT YOUR WEBHOOK HERE");

  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

  const params = {
    username: "My Webhook Name",
    avatar_url: "",
    content: "This message should be latitude and longitude. I spent 2 hours trying to figure this out, help."
  }

  request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. It would be helpful to include *what is actually going wrong*--you can send any data you want.

Comment: So why are you not sending the value from the showPosition method which has the lat and lng?

Comment: Values are values. Doesn’t matter from where (excluding perhaps strings and taintedness, which this is not). So focus on why the values are not sent. Substitute in placeholders and compare. Work backwards.

Comment: @epascarello I tried it, failed. I probably did something wrong there.

Comment: @user2864740 Alright, I will make a new html file and work it out. I hope I get it.

Comment: @DaveNewton Edited, but still looks the same, it is hard to explain because I am very new to javascript.

Comment: What does "the webhook refuses to work" mean? " please try sending the values to your own webhook, make one on discord (it is 100% free) before putting an answer" - are you serious?